# Unable to select different rendering library other than latest in IntelliJ 13.1.4

Tags: android, intellij-idea

For some odd reason, I'm unable to select a different Android version for rendering layouts. Below is a screenshot of the installed SDKs:

[image: screenshot of android adk manager]

[image: screenshot of intellij]

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - apparently it was an issue with the manifest file.